# Roboelectric, building test project (deckard-gradle), failing with space in the folder name

Tags: android, maven, gradle

On Windows 7, issuing "gradlew clean test" command, got me

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 22: file:/C:/Users/Dmitriy Kur/.m2/repository/org/robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/android-all-4.3_r2-robolectric-0.jar
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:226)

...
```

Are we back in DOS times)? No spaces in the path allowed)

As for workaround: any ideas? It's very hard to change user folder name on windows (requires horsing around with regedit).

I'm not sure how to change the default path for maven default repository folder either (because there's no so to speak stable mvn install, no maven config file, everything is done on the fly I think).Changing the maven local path would help to solve the problem for now. Any advice on how to do this (with gradle)? Thank you.

Comment: Came across that old post of mine, the answer seemed to be to use mklink tool in windows command prompt to make a symbolic link to directory name. Make sure to launch command prompt with admin rights.
mklink "User%20Name" "User Name"